# Comparing object to ArrayList in Dictionary Program

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Dictionary
{
protected static int line_number = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    List<Dict> my_collection = new ArrayList<Dict>();
    List<Dict> search_term = new ArrayList<Dict>(); 
    File filename = new File("dict.txt");       

    try
    {
        Scanner data_store = new Scanner(filename);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            while(data_store.hasNextLine())
            {
                String word = data_store.nextLine();
                Dict m = new Dict(word);
                my_collection.add(m);
                line_number++;
            }

            System.out.println(my_collection.size() + " words were loaded.");
            System.out.println("What word are you looking for?");
            String find_word = keyboard.nextLine();
            while(!(find_word.equals("no")))
            {
                Dict n = new Dict(find_word);
                for(line_number = 0; line_number < my_collection.size(); line_number++)
                {
                    if(my_collection.get(line_number).equals(n))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\"" + find_word + "\" is at index " + line_number);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Search again?");
                find_word = keyboard.nextLine();
            }
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Nope!");
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to go through a Dictionary.txt file, called dict.txt here, putting it in an ArrayList (This seems to work) and allowing an input that will output the location of that word in the ArrayList. I tried to do this by turning the user_input into an object that the ArrayList consists of, but I'm unable to compare the two so that I could output the correct instance of the object in the ArrayList. Please help!

Comment: You need to override equals() and hashCode() in Dict class. Moreover, if your Dict class contains only a string instance member representing the word, then you might as well replace Dict with String and check again. And,   why you want to reassign static variable line_number to 0 and use it for iteration? This will also cause some problems right?

Comment: Did you overwrite the equals method for the Dict class

Comment: Also, using a break if you have found a match is usually indicated unless your dictionary is meant to contain homonyms.

Answer (score 1):

What is Dict... if it is your custom class, then make this class to implement Comparable Interface.

```
class Dict implements Comparable<Dict>
{
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Dict other)
 {
  //here you can call "compareTo on Strings or equals on String
 }
}
```

using Comparable interface has advantage as now we can call various `Arrays` utility class method on Dict.

Or as a simpler approach just override `equals` method in Dict class. But then you also need to override `hashCode` method, just so contract between `hashCode` and `equals` maintains all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the above program is that you are comparing the objects of dict class. But actually you have to compare the string stored inside the dict object.

for example, if the dict class uses a String variable named 'inp' then use the following code..
if(my_collection.get(line_number).inp.contains(n.inp))
....

Otherwise implement the comparable interface and override the compareTo method in dict class.